# SSRS Report Stuck on Loading

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am loading a report in a SSRS Report in a ASPX page and whenever I try to load it it gets stuck on Loading. Now, initially I was inputting the parameters directly into the texboxes provided by the SSRS applet, and the report loaded without issue. Now I am inputting the parameters directly through C# code and it gets stuck in that loading screen I mentioned. I checked the parameters (set the code to true) and it showed me that the parameter fields were filling up correctly with the data I was passing. This is the codebehind:

```
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://servername:80/ReportServer_MSSQLSERVER2012"); // Report Server URL
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Test/Report2"; // Report Name
        ReportViewer1.ShowParameterPrompts = true;
        ReportViewer1.ShowPrintButton = true;


        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[] Param = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter[4];
                    Param[0] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("ID", Convert.ToString(Session["aCode"]));
        Param[1] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("IDATE", "02/02/2002");
        Param[2] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("FDATE", "11/06/2013");
        Param[3] = new Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportParameter("Acct", "2005");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(Param);
       //ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

I am manually passing the last values to see how its responding. It still doesn't load even when the Refresh command is uncommented. If anyone can shed some light I'd greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems the mistake was mine. I was putting that code under the "Load" process, and I decided to put the code under a Button press. With the button press everything displays correctly, and if I decide to add it under Page_Load I must use the "if isPostback" type of code to stop an endless loop.